# Open a popup window in the center of the monitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I am trying to open a popup window in the center of the monitor. As I know screen size of each desktop or laptop will vary. So that is the reason I am looking for some way so that whenever my code tries to open a popup window it should get opened in the center of the browser.

Below is my code-

```
<html>

<head>
<style>

* { font-family: Trebuchet MS; }
#containerdiv {width:90%; height: 90%; display: none; position: fixed;margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 5%; background:#FFF; border: 1px solid #666;border: 1px solid #555;box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222; z-index: 999999;}
/*#containerdiv iframe {display:none; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; border: none; }*/
#blockdiv {background: #000; opacity:0.6;  position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
ul { padding:10px; background: #EEE; position: absolute; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;}
ul li {color: #222; padding: 10px; font-size: 22px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;  }
h3 { font-size: 26px; padding:18px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; }
#close { top: 13px;position: absolute;right: 13px; padding: 10px; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#close:hover {  cursor: pointer; background: #E5E5E5 }

#apply { top: 13px;position: absolute;left: 13px; padding: 10px; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#apply:hover {  cursor: pointer; background: #E5E5E5 }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

function open(url) {
    $('#blockdiv').fadeIn();
    $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
    $('#containerdiv').fadeIn();   
}

function close() {  
    $('#blockdiv').fadeOut();
    $('#containerdiv').fadeOut();  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').css({width: $('#containerdiv').width()-20,height:    $('#containerdiv').height()-90})

     $('#close').click( function() { close() })
     $('#apply').click( function() { open('http://www.google.com/') })

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="apply">ApplyOnline</span>
<div id="blockdiv"></div>
<div id="containerdiv">
    <iframe id="iframe" style="width:100%; height: 100%; outline: 1px solid red;"></iframe>
    <span id="close">Close</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But somehow the above code, doesn't gets opened in the center of the monitor. Can anybody help me on this? What changes I need to make in the above code so that it always open the popup window in the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

you can center you popup in css like

this is only css method to make it center so no js will be required to center it

```
#containerdiv {
    width:90%;
    height: 90%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-45% 0 0 -45%;
    background:#FFF;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 40px #222;
    z-index: 999999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears centered within the browser window to me.

If you want to center it based on screen resolution of the client's monitor you can use:

```
var centerDiv=function(){
    var popUpHeight=$('#containerdiv').height();
    var popUpWidth=$('#containerdiv').width();
    var yPos=(window.screen.availHeight/2)-(popUpHeight/2)-window.screenY-(window.outerHeight-window.innerHeight);
    var xPos=(window.screen.availWidth/2)-(popUpWidth/2)-window.screenX-(window.outerWidth-window.innerWidth);
    $('#containerdiv').css({position:"absolute",top: yPos+"px",left: xPos+"px"});
}
window.onload=centerDiv();
var lastX = window.screenX;
var lastY = window.screenY;
var lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
var lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
setInterval(function(){
  if(lastX != window.screenX || lastY != window.screenY || lastHeight != window.outerHeight || lastWidth != window.outerWidth){
    centerDiv();
  }

  oldX = window.screenX;
  oldY = window.screenY;
}, 33);
```

Comment: where should I add this piece code? And do I need to remove anything if I am adding this piece of code?

Comment: You could append it your document ready event. There is an issue with this code though. You would need to also find the distance of the browser view port from the edges of the screen as well and subtract those. Give me a moment, and I'll see if I can edit my answer to take that into account as well.

Comment: I've changed the code. It's not perfect, but it does a pretty decent job. It acts funny, I noticed, with the chrome debugger up. I don't know if there's a way to enhance this, but it works pretty well for now. It will also update the position on the box at a rate of 30 frame per second. Try it out by moving the window around the screen. Let me know if this helps. Thanks.
Edit: I forgot to mention, to do this, set your width and height to an explicit pixel value and remove your margin.